# Making wordpress plugin, need help to figure out best approach for curl and tables

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, curl

Hi i'm making a Wordpress plugin that queries a service via an API for information, however i'm trying to wrap my head around how to approach this the best way.

The service response very slowly, even after sending data in bulk. If i use the suggested curl code the page takes many many seconds to load.

I have to send details of items to the API and get a response back to show the admin of details for every item that needs to be shipped. So far i can get the data and populate the table but the service has a very very slow response. I as thinking of using ajax but i suck at Javascript and a lot of Javascript doesn't seem to work with Wordpress because of how differently the front-end is implemented, even echo from PP doesn't show up either unless its wrapped in html code.

I would prefer to have the data request and load not be blocking to the page rendering as nothing is shown on the browser for many many seconds.

Comment: Note: i rejected the edit because of spelling mistakes that changed the meaning.

Comment: Note: I just made the changes to make it grammatically correct, I don't think the meaning of question is changing anywhere.

Comment: no i mean im not stuck at javascript, i suck at javascript